# How to send non-transactional emails automatically from website

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have used SendGrid or Mandrill to send transactional emails from websites, but I would like to send automated emails that are notifying subscribers when something is added to the website that matches their criteria. I would like to use a cron job to check my mysql database to see if there is new "matches" and send an email to notify customers. I know how to write scripts to do all of that except for the actual sending the email part because I don't want to use the PHP mail function in case the volume of emails gets too high and SendGrid or Mandrill are only for transactional emails. Thanks!

Comment: Use the SendGrid API from the script you using the cron job.

Comment: You could use phpmailer or swift mailer.

Comment: I've looked up the [definition for transactional email](https://mailchimp.com/marketing-glossary/transactional-email/) and I can't see why this use case wouldn't fall into the category. Do your providers have terms of use that explicitly ban them or something?

Answer (score 0):

The Mandrill API (mailchimp actually) provides you with endpoints to send your own html content, or use templates that you can provide variables to, through their API. **Basically, your cron job has to call the API and that's it.**

**[send email through API with your own html content](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-new-message/)**

**[send email through API with a template created in mandrill](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-using-message-template/)**